# How can an object lose energy but still move at the same speed with constant momentum?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy, momentum, temperature

I'm studying collisions, and while doing it, the conservation of momentum seems to strike me in a weird way.

If the momentum in a system is constant but energy can still be lost through thermal radiation, wouldn't this mean that a particle can lose most of its energy while still moving at the same speed?

Is the momentum accounting for some emission of a heat particle that I forgot the name (some less-used brother of the photon)?

Or maybe conservation of energy and momentum are unrelated?

Comment: They are related. Thermal (electromagnetic) radiation has momentum as well as energy - but you need to study special relativity to understand what that sentence really means.

Comment: Unfortunately it's going to take a long time for me to get there :'( 
But it's good to know i'm not off track

Comment: First thing to remember is there are no true closed systems because of photons. Also a Particle can have two kinds of energy. Linear momentum and internal energy like rotation or heat. You can lose or gain one of those energies without affecting the other.

Comment: You seem to have asked several questions, none of which match the title.  FWIW,  a temperature of 0 K  means there's only one available energy state, not that there is no energy whatsoever.

Comment: @BillAlsept it makes sense, but at the same time, since it seems to conflict with the answer i got from anna v, i'm not sure how to think about it.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft sorry man, but even though i remember hearing about the energy state way of describing something thermodynamically(i think it was on entropy), i have no idea how that relates to temperature. 
And i think the question relates well. But i'm not even close to be a expert on the field, so i could be wrong...

Comment: @HighlightXII no problem - yes, I use the Statistical Mechanics definition where temperature is  $T = \frac{dU}{dS}$  ; the kinetic energy definition ignores any "internal zero-point energy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temperature is a thermodynamic variable , i.e. it depends on a large number of particles because it can be measured in matter, and thermodynamics as a theory developed long before the particle nature of matter was studied. When  Newtonian mechanics was developed, it was shown that the theory of thermodynamics emerged from [statistical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics) .

In statistical mechanics [temperature is :](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.htm)

$$T_{kinetic}=\frac 2{3k}\left[\,\,\overline{ \frac 1 2 m v^2 }\,\,\right]=\frac 2{3k}KE_{avg}$$

related to the average kinetic energy, and through that to the average momentum.

You ask

> If the momentum in a system is constant

The average momentum can be considered constant,

> but you could still lose your energy by thermal radiation,

thermal radiation is electromagnetic waves, and they do carry energy and momentum , that is how [black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) leaves a massive object.

> wouldn't this mean that a particle can lose most of its energy while still moving at the same speed?

Now you are confusing statistical averages with individual interactions. As kinetic energy and momentum are related functionally, a particle cannot lose kinetic energy and keep the same speed.

> Is the momentum accounting for some emission of a heat particle

the changes in momentum due to collisions and interactions do come from the radiated eletromagnetic radiation, as the object cools.

> that i forgot the name(some less used brother of the photon)?

there is no brother of the photon, photons are what electromagnetic radiation is made up of.

Comment: So does this means that if that particle keeps emitting electromagnetic radiation long enough it will eventually stop?

Comment: @HighlightXII the particle will stop radiating if it reaches  a temperature of absolute zero, but if the particle also had linear momentum it will keep going until it is stopped by something.

Comment: @BillAlsept  A particle has a velocity, not a temperature, By imagination we can call the kinetic energy of the particle as its temperature,  but then it means that to call it  0 K  its velocity would be zero.

Comment: @HighlightXII a single individual charged particle can lose all its velocity to radiation and stop. 0 K is approached as a limit, and it is an average of the kinetic energies of the material, the smaller the kinetic energy of individual particles the closer to 0.

Comment: this is of interest https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/racing-toward-absolute-zero/

Comment: Tnx for the anwser @annav, feeling enlightened right now :3